# Куди і навіщо летить посошок?

Tags: значення-слів

У «Вечірній казці від діда Панаса» актор Петро Вескляров цитує віршик:
([YouTube video](https://youtu.be/lwVMsA5IUoQ))

> *Спи, мій маленький, цить. І зайчик сіренький спить.
>
>   Сплять при дорозі воли, сплять на відлозі орли.
>
>   Сплять наші рідні краї, ниви дорідні й гаї.
>
>   Тільки не спить пастушок. Свиснув<sup>(1)</sup> — **летить посошок**.
>
>   Спи, мій маленький, цить. І зайчик сіренький спить.*

Цікаво, що таке посошок, і навіщо він летить?

Словники [зазвичай стверджують](http://sum.in.ua/s/posokh), що *посошок* — зменшено-пестлива форма до *посох*, який, у свою чергу, визначається як палиця, яку використовують для опори при ходьбі. Але у такому випадку, не дуже зрозуміло, яким чином повʼязані свист, кидання палиці для ходіння і звичайна діяльність пастуха.

Відповідно, має бути якесь інше значення слова «посошок»?

---

<sup>(1)</sup> у деяких джерелах — «кинув».

Comment: Про натурити? Напишіть питання :)
Ось знайшов у джерелах:
http://ukrlit.org/barka_vasyl_kostiantynovych/zhovtyi_kniaz/73
Поночі вони вивели лоша і стали наганяти на каміння. Мирону Даниловичу не вдавалося з свого боку налякати, як слід, і лоша, підбрикуючи вузькими ногами, пробігало мимо. От перейняв його і *натурив* прямо на компаньйона, який тільки того ждав: так ударив лозиною і затупотів, замахав чорними рукавами, що воно, з великого переляку, помчало просто на каміння і зломило ліву передню ногу.

Про "летить посошок" джерел не маю, лише практика :)

Comment: @hutorny відповідь не обов'язково має бути підкріплена джерелами, у багатьох випадках джерел просто нема.

Answer (score 2):

На мою думку

> Свиснув — летить посошок

описує узвичаєну практику пастухів, які в критичних ситуаціях кидають посох, щоб відігнати скотину від місць, де вона може завдати шкоди. Свист чи окрик при цьому також грають важливу роль — вони привертають увагу скотини. Навіть якщо посох не долетить, але скотина його побачить — вона з більшою ймовірністю відреагує потрібним чином, ніж коли не побачить і посох не долетить.

Comment: Ще додам, що використання пастухами посоха — поширена практика.  Словосполучення «пастуший посох» описане [в російській Вікіпедії](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Посох) і посох як засіб пастуха є на [зображеннях в англійській](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herder) і [згадується](//dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/biblerus/71185/посох) навіть у Біблії. Щоправда це стосується лише факту використання посоху, а не згадок про його кидання.

Comment: «…Один з ґирлиґою, жезлом пастуха, що засвідчує приналежність до найдавнішого фаху людського…» (Олесь Гончар «Тронка»), «Федір і Павло разом взяли до рук пастуші кийки…» (Юрій Мушкетик «Серце і камінь»). Ще його називають _ціпком_: «ґирлиґа, рідко ґерлиґа — ціпок, часто загнутий на кінці, яким користуються пастухи, старі люди і т. ін.» («Словник української мови» в 11 томах).

Comment: Цікава версія, але вона повністю розбігається з контекстом віршика. Нагадую: «**Сплять** при дорозі воли, **сплять** на відлозі орли.» Arguably, коли худоба **спить**, вона досить рідко робить шкоду і ще рідше бачить посох, який летить. :-) А сам пастушок у цій ситуації виглядає як злобний троль, який будить худобу, що відпочиває.

Comment: Множина *при дорозі воли* не  тотожна множині "худоба під котролем пастушка" :)

Comment: @hutorny, якщо настільки прискіпливо розглядати слова, то там написано — «**тільки** не спить пастушок». Іншими словами, усі інші сплять: зайчик сіренький, воли, орли, рідні краї тощо. В тому числі, *худоба під контролем пастушка*.

Comment: Пастухи, аби не тягати з собою «посошок» – дебелий ціпок, часто, коли гнали худобу або йшли кудись, просто кидали ціпок поперед себе, а як доходили до нього, то піднімали й знову кидали вперед, і т. д. Там у віршику ніч, а вночі, здається, лише коней пасуть, а табуну коней вовки не дуже страшні, навряд чи він кидав ціпок аби відігнати вовків.